# Can i select ion2-calendar range starting from tomorrow to 3 months from that date?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have setup an ion-calendar using ion2-calendar plugin. Previous Dates are disabled before today. But i want to disable "today" also and show open dates starting from tomorrow. And also want the "to" date only till 3 months of start date.

i have tried giving [optionsRange] and from: new Date(); gives it has today. The [optionsRange] will work if i hard code the values the date, but i want it dynamic. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar

```
HTML CODE:

<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="startDate" 
              [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
              [options]="optionsRange">
</ion-calendar>

TS FILE CODE:

optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
        color: "primary",
        from: new Date()+1,
                to: new Date() + 90
};
```

Obviously it is throwing an error stating i can't "+" and number in the method.

But i want from: ( Tomorrow's DATE )   and   to: ( 3 months from start Date )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the Solution

```
   <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="this.dateRange"
                  (onChange)="onChange($event)"
                  [options]="option"
                  type="string"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD">
    </ion-calendar>
```

.ts

```
 dateRange: {
    from: Date;
    to: Date
  } = {
    from:  new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 *2),
    to: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 90)
  };

  option: CalendarModalOptions = {
    pickMode: 'range',
    title: 'RANGE',
    defaultDateRange: this.dateRange
  };


onChange($event) {
    console.log($event)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have implemented the same but looks like the calendar is not impacted any way, still see the dates. Can you give a plnkr link if possible?

Comment: i have edited and run original repo https://github.com/ChanakaWeerasinghe/ion-calander

Comment: It is helpful accept answer it will helpfull futer users to

Comment: The above solution worked, but is there any way to disable specific dates? Like for example if i need Dec 31st disabled, is that something we can achieve? Because the above formula works with respect to present date.

Answer (score 0):

below i am mention ts and html code for ionic 4 this will solve your problem

ts file

```
import { CalendarComponentOptions, DayConfig , CalendarModal, CalendarModalOptions} from 'ion2-calendar';
export class CalenderPage implements OnInit {
test: DayConfig[]=[];
public optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
  //from: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
  from: new Date(2019, 11, 1),
  to: new Date(2020, 2, 15),
  pickMode: 'range',
  daysConfig: this.test
};

constructor(
    public datepipe: DatePipe,
  ) {
   //disable next date from today and previous date from one month after
      var now = new Date();
      this.optionsRange.from = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()-30);
      this.optionsRange.to = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
}
}
```

in html

```
<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateRange" [readonly]="false" [options]="optionsRange" (change)="onChange($event, 2)" [type]="type" [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'" >
</ion-calendar>
```